# Advanced custom field with short codes

Tags: wordpress, frontend, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

Can i display the data which are in the advanced custom fields using shortcodes without editing theme codes, in my web page front end. If the answer is yes, how can i do this? If not are there any methods to do that easily without deep coding knowledge.

chatGPT says yes but I couldn’t.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. There is an ACF shortcode. See here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/shortcode/

`[acf field="field_name"]`

You can also pass a post id to get the field of another post:

`[acf field="field_name" post_id="123"]`

However, this does not work for all field types. But there is a Wordpress plugin with which you can display the custom fields called ACF Views: https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-views/